# Debugging iphone app

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios

How do I debug an iPhone aplication? How can I find out what's going on in the simulator? I'm a beginner in Xcode development and don't know what's the problem with the code below. The app is crashing on button click.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    [myLabel setText:@"Labela"];
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50.0,50.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];

    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [myButton addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(buttonAction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [myButton setTitle:@"Klikni" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0)];

    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)buttonAction {
    [myLabel setText:@"Promijenjen!"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
action:@selector(buttonAction:)
```

Here you specify that buttonAction selector gets 1 parameter, but it is declared to have none:

```
- (void)buttonAction{
...
```

So when button click system tries to call undefined method and that results in crash. To fix that you should either change selector name to

```
action:@selector(buttonAction)
```

or change action method declaration:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender{
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Click "Build & Run" button to debug. Click "Show console" button. Use NSLog and breakpoints.
Try declaring: -(void) buttonAction:(id) sender;

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner, you should start with a tutorial or better, a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449101/iphone-development-books) about the subject.

You can output a message to the console using `NSLog(@"My variable value: %@", myVariable);`

You can use Debugging, line by line, just add a breakpoint anywhere in the code and Run as Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://tinyurl.com/28x3ywj).

In all seriousness, apple has a [fairly decent guide for debugging using XCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, change

`action:@selector(buttonAction:)`

To

`action:@selector(buttonAction)`

For general debugging, try readin Apple debugging guide, which can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html

You are going to want learn about using the debugger (Cmd +Shift + Y) and the console, accessible with the keyboard shortcut, Cmd +Shift + R.

Good luck!